# Button click listener in a separate fragment not working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to add a button clicker listener in my fragment but it doesn't seem to work.

My main fragment is created to show tabs of two other fragments. Now, this tabs fragment has a button in the toolbar to filter content. This filter button's listener and method are in my two other fragments. The issue is, when clicking on the button, it does nothing.

Tabs Fragment:

```
public class LibraryFragment extends Fragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

   private View view;
   private SectionsPagerAdapterLib PageAdapter;
   public ViewPager viewPager;
   private ImageView filterBtn;

   private LibraryFragment.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

   public interface OnItemClickListener {
       void onItemClick(View view);
   }

   public void setOnItemClickListener(LibraryFragment.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
       this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;

   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       this.view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library_tabs, container, false);

       TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.fav_list_tabs);
       filterBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.filterBtn);
       viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.fav_list_tabs_container);

       filterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                   mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v);
               }
           }
       });

       PageAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapterLib(getFragmentManager(), getActivity());
       viewPager.setAdapter(PageAdapter);
       viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
       viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
       tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

       getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
       getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.mWindowColorHeaders));

       return view;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onPageSelected(int position) {

       Fragment fragment = PageAdapter.getFragment(position);
       if (fragment != null) {
           fragment.onResume();
       }

   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

   }

}
```

Fragment which is supposed to work when the button is clicked:

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment implements LibraryFragment.OnItemClickListener {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // find my views, etc
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view) {

        //populate filter list
        if (Constants.genreList != null){
            list.add(0, "All Filters");
            for (int i = 0; i < Constants.list.size(); i++) {
                list.add((i + 1), Constants.list.get(i).getName());
            }
        }
        final String[] listArray = new String[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            listArray[i] = list.get(i);
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Select Filter");
        builder.setItems(genreArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                //    ((TextView) v).setText(genreArray[i]);
                selected_list.setText(listArray[i]);
                if (i == 0) {
                    getData(1);
                }
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: show how are you switching/showing your `Fragment`s, especially when/where you are calling `setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: @snachmsm that's the issue, I don't know where to call my setOnItemClickListener. I'm new to android development and learning online so it's getting a little difficult. LibraryFragment loads from MainActivity class which has bottom navigation.

Answer (score 0):

try this in a fragment

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {                    //change fragment_video to where your button is located//
        final View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video,container,false);
        //start stream Button
        Button startButton = (Button)v2.findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //what your button is going to do
            }
        });
        return v2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As fragments are handled by Activity ,Fragments are still not depend on each other and can be used in one or two pane mode. Activity should handle listeners of both fragments.